# Attempt to make the unique windows login insert an actual scanned picture file in Excel

Tags: windows, excel, vba, authentication, signature

I will try to make this as clear as possible, and any help is appreciated. So thanks in advance.
I am wanting to create an inspection form template that will automatically pull the windows login information, then go to a server location and pull in a (same as login)named picture file with an .jpg or .png of the users actual penned signature to sign several tabs in the same excel file.

Windows User id's are unique as this is a business.  The server location will not change paths. The server file location will need to be locked to read only so it can not be tampered with, which should not interfere with reading a file to insert it(mentioning it just in case).

I want the user to open the blank form I create.  Their windows login information will automatically fill in the signature box.  And when they have completed the inspection, they can print to pdf and save in the proper filled in form location. I do not want nor need the information to stay static across other computers in the excel file.  if the local user saves a copy they wish to update, it will only see their signature.

I would prefer the unique username to update the the users actual name, which could be kept in a locked excel file on the server as well, but that might be asking too much and I can have them type it in if needed.

All of the signatures on the file would be the same.

EDIT - recorded macro

```
Sub Sig_server2() 
' Sig_server2 Macro 
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s 

    Environ ("username") ' supposed to define the variable based
                         ' on the windows login information 

    Sheets("Inspectiontype").Select ' Selects the tab to add the signature on 
    Range("H19:R19").Select 'Selects the range where picture is to be inserted 

    ' need "jamesmor" to change to the "username" variable
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Y:\QA\Signatures\jamesmor.png").Select 

    Range("S19:V19").Select ' Drops to the next blank to be filled
                            ' in which is the inspection stamp number
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from doing this?  You've just stated a list of requirements, without explaining what your problem is.

Comment: not sure how your usernames are set up but you might be able to use the environment variable, e.g., `Environ("username")` should return the windows username. That is what we use on applications I develop; not for security purposes but just to log errors, who's accessing databases, how often, etc.  Once you know the username, getting the file from a known location with a known name should not be terribly difficult.

Comment: @Tim: What is stopping me from doing this? I cannot find the button in excel 2013 to click that will insert a signature file based on the windows login. I need some type of visual basic code, or something else to make this happen. Sorry for not being clear enough. I'm so far from knowing what the answer is, that I'm obviously not asking the question in a manner that makes sense.

David: Again my clarity was lacking. I've no more than touched VB. I stumbled across this site as it had intelligent answers to questions which seemed similar to mine. "Environ("username")" where would this be put?

Comment: (Cont'd) I've no doubt with the level of user here that I can get the information I need. Imagine this is an exercise in how to program a computer to make a peanut butter and jelly sandwich. I don't have a clue how to farm peanuts and though the information might be useful, it's a bit overkill on what I actually need.  I'm after a way to program excel, in such a manner, as to automatically pull the windows login information, and in turn, pull a server based picture file to insert into a cell. I'm honestly not sure how to re-state it.

Comment: (cont'd) If you have neither the patience nor the time to explain it down to my level, I completely understand(no sarcasm). I however still have to ask as it is a valid need on my end.

Comment: Try recording a macro as you insert a signature file from the server - that's usually a good place to start if you're just starting with VBA.

Comment: [/code].Sub Sig_server2()
' Sig_server2 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
    Environ ("username") ' supposed to define the variable based on the windows login information
    Sheets("Inspectiontype").Select 'Selects the tab to add the signature on
    Range("H19:R19").Select  'Selects the range where picture is to be inserted
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Y:\QA\Signatures\jamesmor.png").Select 'need "jamesmor" to change to the "username" variable.
    Range("S19:V19").Select 'Drops to the next blank to be filled in which is the inspection stamp number[code]

    
End Sub

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about the macro system. I've dropped the original picture in there, and will try to show the code if I can figure out how to set that up in the comments.  If I could figure out where to put the "Environ("username")" and replace "jamesmor" in my current call of:    "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Y:\QA\Signatures\jamesmor.png").Select  "   I'll keep searching basic vb commands to see if I can get there.  At least I'm one step closer, so thanks for the shove in the right direction.

Comment: @tim Thank you for the exact answer I needed.  You not only gave my the answer, but helped direct me into asking a question in a manner that made sense enough to answer.  Hopefully someday I'll know enough to be able to help someone else. In the interim, if there is some way to assist you rating here let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
Sub Tester()
    Const SERVER_PATH As String = "Y:\QA\Signatures\"
    Dim usr As String, fPath As String

    usr = Environ("username")
    fPath = SERVER_PATH & usr & ".png"

    If Dir(fPath, vbNormal) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Signature file for '" & usr & "' not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    InsertPicFile fPath, Sheets("Inspectiontype").Range("H19")
    '...do other inserts

End Sub

Sub InsertPicFile(sigPath As String, rng As Range)
    With rng.Parent.Pictures.Insert(sigPath)
        .Left = rng.Cells(1).Left
        .Top = rng.Cells(1).Top
    End With
End Sub
```